# Detecting and correcting collisions in (Zorbist) hashing to avoid errors in transposition table

Tags: hash, hash-tables, hashing, board-games

**Context**

Say I have a transposition table that uses keys produced by (e.g. Zorbist) hashing game positions.

The table has a finite recycled memory (`key % p` is the `index` of the key, `p` is table size and prime).

That is, at `table[index(key)]` (there) we store `key` and (game position) `evaluation`.

So, when fetching cached evaluation of a game position `P` that was hashed into `key`:

- If `key` matches with key stored at `index(key)`, we return `evaluation` stored there.
- Else, we return default value (indicating "empty"), then rewrite `key` and `evaluation` there.

*(I've basically summarized how a simple transposition table can be implemented.)*

**Collision problem**

The problem is when two different game positions `P1` and `P2` are hashed into the same `key` (collision).

Say that we encounter position `P1` first. First time reading this `key`, "empty" value will be returned and `evaluation1` for `P1` will be stored in `table[index(key)]`. Second time reading this `key` (matching key at index), `evaluation1` for `P1` will be returned. This will either:

- Be fine, in the case that we encountered `P1` again.
- Be an error in the game evaluation, in the case that we encountered `P2`.

> How can this error be detected and corrected, efficently?

Apparently [stockfish uses something like this Zorbist hashing](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/35131/12314) and has verification *"Every entry is carefully validated before use,..."*, meaning that *"...this (game engine) would work even if every hash table access would return random numbers."*; But, how is this verification implemented?

Comment: You don't correct zobrist hash collisions.In [this](https://craftychess.com/hyatt/collisions.html) paper, Robert Hyatt(creator of Crafty Engine) ran a test where he forced the transposition table to have collisions. He and Anthony Cozzie(creator of Zappa) concluded that the cost of a collision here and there will not significantly change the evaluation of the position, and 64 bit keys are enough.
Also, you cannot detect zobrist hash collisions. It is impossible to go from a zobrist hash back to a chess position, and storing the whole position in the transposition table takes too much memory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any particular experience with transposition tables in particular, but in general, the standard way to use a hash table stores the key (e.g., the value P1 or P2) in the entry, not the hash of the key.  This way you can detect collisions.

Terminology: in standard hash table usage, the key is the value (i.e., the position, such as P1 or P2), not its hash.

There are many standard ways to resolve collisions in hash tables, e.g., using open chaining or closed chaining.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table.  However, I suspect those are not needed for transposition tables, as I suspect it is  fine to return "unknown" in the event of a collision.  If so, you might not need any of those methods.

Comment: I'm not concerned with that type of collisions (my hash function that compute the index is simple modulo p, prime size), i.e. I'm not concerned with the transposition table hashing. Instead, note that people combine transposition tables with additional (e.g. Zorbist) **hashing of keys to save space** (smaller keys). Then they usually try to minimize collisions of hashed keys in various ways, as they will inevitably happen. Instead of minimizing collisions, I'm wondering if there's a way to efficiently detect and correct those collisions, maybe using properties of Zorbist or some other hash.

Comment: You’d often store the hashed value to have a very fast check that you found the right value, but for chess positions you could have a hash value that is actually a subset of the position.

Comment: For chess positions, you could create a 64 or 96 bit hash values. With 96 bits, you’d have to lookup 2^48 positions on average until you get the wrong result, and then it is most likely that one incorrect lookup doesn’t affect the result. Having a bigger hashtable, saving time and calculating further, may very well outweigh the risk of very rare non-optimal results.