# How to properly save Zobrist Keys?

Tags: hash, hash-tables, hashing

In a project of mine, I want to represent states as efficiently as possible. Initially, I went ahead with a BitBoard representation and some clever tricks to speed up the evaluation of the game tree. That works fine. Though when looking up any given state in the Look-Up table, I need to do some heavy calculations.

After some research, I found a solution that seems to solve my issues: [Zobrist Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing). My game state comprises about ~370 possible fields to fill - depending on the encoding. After populating all fields of my array with randomly generated numbers (I used the default [Random class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) from [`java.lang`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)) I tested XORing fields together. *Everything works smoothly.*

But I got two unanswered *(which are closely entangled)* questions left:

**1.** If I save the states in a look-up database, I should save the initial randomly generated array in order to reproduce the same look-up key each time. If I don't do this, I would need to save other data (such as which fields are XORed together) in order to check the look-up table - but this would render the whole idea of Zobrist hashing (or hashing in general) useless.

**2.** I can't verify if the approach yields any collisions UNLESS (once again) I save other data - such as which fields were XORed together to get the Zobrist hash.

I other posts on [how to detect collisions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/141520/detecting-and-correcting-collisions-in-zorbist-hashing-to-avoid-errors-in-tran), [how the popular Stockfish engine approaches the issue](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/fc5b59b88bae00b7e74bbad0de7c3c33136937cf/src/position.cpp), [the mathematical aspects](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982274/zobrist-hashing-collision-probability-64-bit-vs-twice-32-bit) and much more, but wasn't able to find a summarizing answer:

**In general**, using Zobrist hashing, how and which data should one save in order to cross-verify the data in a look-up table? Should I first try to check a few billion rounds for collisions and re-generate random numbers once I found too many over a given treshhold? Should I just generate and save the Zobrist numbers to load up every run of the programme - hoping no collisions appear?

Comment: My line of thought goes along the following concept: `initZobrist()` -> `validateZobrist()` (usually not done - why?) -> `saveZobristNumbers()` -> `hash()`.
Randomly generating with init() each and every time seems counter-intuitive - unless you save configurations of the board along with it to validate the board (which would make the hashing useless imo). Furthermore, why does no code snippet I looked at preserve the Zobrist array for future access? Why do many implementations save additional information?

Comment: What do you mean by "cross-verify the data"?  What task are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you trying to deal with collisions in the hash?  It seems like this is the same question as https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/141520/755.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing#Use_of_the_hash_value and https://www.chessprogramming.org/Zobrist_Hashing#Collisions.